# oracle adf page not work on NOKIA Mobile Browser

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I have oracle adf jspx page
when i browse this page on NOKIA Mobile Browser adf component not work like buttons(you cant press button)
any suggestion !

Answer (score 2):

You can see below the list of browsers supported by ADF:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/121300-cert-2164864.html

Comment: ADF is not supposed to work on Nokia Mobile browser, as per above link.